# When does Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() return null?

Tags: wpf, winapi, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

[OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx)'s [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.showdialog.aspx) method returns a nullable boolean, set to true if the user clicked OK or false if he clicked Cancel. When does it return `null`? The documentation does not say.

Comment: "Curiosity" is a perfectly good answer, but I'm curious to know why you ask?  Why not just compare what it returns to "true" (TryParse, etc, etc) and roll on?

Comment: Just wondering why they use a nullable boolean over a standard one. Comparing against true works fine, as you suggested.

Comment: Now you've got me curious, too.  Hopefully someone will come along with a good answer!

Comment: Is a nullable boolean returned only by WPF's ShowDialog (and not WinForms')?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is stated in the questions linked below, but I'll mention here that [Programming WPF (Chris Sells, Ian Griffiths)](http://books.google.com/books?id=558i6t1dKEAC&lpg=PA323&ots=gZtcCBCWJL&dq=WPF%20ShowDialog%20nullable%20boolean&pg=PA333#v=onepage&q=WPF%20ShowDialog%20nullable%20boolean&f=false) says:

> ShowDialog will always return true or
>   false. ... Only after a dialog has
>   been shown but before it's been closed
>   is DialogResult null.

Similar question: [When would ShowDialog() return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990109/when-would-showdialog-return-null)

And: [Why is DialogResult a nullable bool in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987224/why-is-dialogresult-a-nullable-bool-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [.NET reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog` is implemented by a base class, `Microsoft.Win32.CommonDialog`. That implementation has only one return clause:

```
return new bool?(this.RunDialog(activeWindow));
```

`RunDialog` returns a `bool`, not a `bool?`.

`bool?` is just a [C# shorthand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx) for `System.Nullable<bool>`. The [constructor of `System.Nullable<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxxazwb.aspx), according to reflector again, sets the value of the nullable to its parameter, and marks its hasValue property as true.

So... you shouldn't ever get a `null` result. A quick test confirms that closing the dialog without canceling (red x button) indeed returns a `false` value, not a `null`.

The Windows Forms version of OpenFileDialog returns a DialogResult, which has a [wider range of values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that OpenFileDialog returns bool? to be consistent with other WPF dialogs that actually can return a null result.