# Checking nullable result of OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, resharper, nullable, openfiledialog

I have written some code in a WPF application, which looks like this:

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = this.FileExtensionFilter };
var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
{
    ... Process result of dialog ...
}
```

All well and good, I thought, but ReSharper has come up with a warning on the check for `dialogResult.HasValue`, "Expression is always true".

The first question is how ReSharper would even know that the dialogResult always has a result - it must have dived right down into the decompiled code of the `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` class and observed that it never returns null. Either that, or it's just a hardcoded warning specifically for this class.

Secondly, it doesn't seem like good practice to just assume that the result will never be null. What if Microsoft release a future version of the library in which the null value does become available? The documentation on the matter says: ["In the current implementation, the derived classes (OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog) will only return true or false"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms614336.aspx) which does imply this is not a permanent arrangement that we can rely on forever.

Any thoughts on whether I'm being overcautious and should remove the line as ReSharper suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem odd. The MSDN spec states that it will return either true or false, but still there must be a reason for the Nullable.

I would absolutely agree with you, that assuming an implementation underneath is bad practise. I would code as per the interface, so in this case I think checking the HasValue is the correct way to go.

How does Re-sharper know? I'm afraid I can't answer that. It's not something I use, they may have hard-coded it.

This may be of interest to you: [When does Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261910/when-does-microsoft-win32-openfiledialog-showdialog-return-null)

It seems the reason there is the possbility of null is because that's the result before the user has closed the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard-coded.

If you look in the ReSharper directory in Program Files, you will see lot's of XML files with **Nullness.Gen** in the names, these contain rules regarding whether or not a particular element is/is not null, and these are used to display warnings such as the one you are seeing, where they wouldn't be displayed normally.

If you find the **2.0.5.0.Nullness.Gen.xml** file in **Bin\ExternalAnnotations.NETFramework\System.Windows**, you will find the following entry about half way down:

```
<member name="M:System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
</member>
```

You can then look at **JetBrains.Annotations** in the **bin** directory to see the definition for **NotNullAttribute**:

```
 <member name="T:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute">
     <summary>
     Indicates that the value of the marked element could never be <c>null</c>
     </summary>
     <example><code>
     [NotNull] public object Foo() {
       return null; // Warning: Possible 'null' assignment
     }
     </code></example>
 </member>
```

Comment: Good work answering the other half of the question - I believe this is a mistake from JetBrains and that it is a really bad assumption still that the API won't return null, it's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks as well for clarifying this JMK. I agree with @Ian, it does seem like bad programming practice to make hardcoded assumptions like this. Public interfaces should generally be regarded as black boxes, and if it has a nullable return type you should cater for that.

Comment: It's a shame I can't mark both answers as accepted, since they each answer a different part of the multiple question! Upvoting both anyway.

Comment: @Ian's answer is more useful so I'm not complaining :)