# Taglib NullException when saving Picture

Tags: c#, taglib

I'm Working on my own tag editor for Mp3 files. It's been good so far until I got stuck on saving the picture to the file. So I did a little searching and found out about these two ways but in both of them when I press the save button on my program a `NullException` occurs and says "value cannot be null" here are the two codes:

```
TagLib.Picture pic = TagLib.Picture.CreateFromPath(PicDir); //occurs here
TagLib.Id3v2.AttachedPictureFrame albumCoverPictFrame = new 
TagLib.Id3v2.AttachedPictureFrame(pic);
albumCoverPictFrame.MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
albumCoverPictFrame.Type = TagLib.PictureType.FrontCover;
TagLib.IPicture[] pictFrames = new IPicture[1];
pictFrames[0] = (IPicture)albumCoverPictFrame;
file.Tag.Pictures = pictFrames;
```

and this one:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(PicDir); //occurs here
TagLib.Picture pic = new TagLib.Picture();
pic.Type = TagLib.PictureType.FrontCover;
pic.Description = "Cover";
pic.MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
ms.Position = 0;
pic.Data = TagLib.ByteVector.FromStream(ms);
file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[] { pic };
ms.Close();
```

I can't find anything on Internet about a `NullException` on saving the pic with TagLib. I'm sure nothing is wrong with the picture directory or the picture itself, so the problem comes from elsewhere.

This is the part where I use `showDialog`

```
private void OpenPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog3.DefaultExt = "JPG";
    openFileDialog3.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    openFileDialog3.Multiselect = false;
    openFileDialog3.FileName = "Choose the Photo";
    openFileDialog3.ShowDialog();
}
```

and here is the `FileOk` part:

```
private void Pic_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    label21.Visible = true;
    PicDir = openFileDialog3.FileName;
    Aks = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `PicDir`? Is it `null`?

Comment: No it contains the picture Directory from a OpenFileDialog

Comment: But you know that `Image.FromFile()` expects the path to the picture (including the filename) and not only a directory.

Comment: So i found out that the openfiledialog is returning null but why?! After opening the file the openfiledialog1.FileName is null

Comment: Here's [when or why OpenFileDialog returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261910/when-does-microsoft-win32-openfiledialog-showdialog-return-null)

Comment: Maybe you could post your code which belongs to the `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: so i edited the question

Comment: And when does the first code get's executed? After the FileOk event?

Comment: @BenjaminJ. yes it does

Comment: It's difficult do solve the problem with that code. Maybe the value of the variable `PicDir` get's changed someone else? Have you tried to set a breakpoint on the line `PicDir = openFileDialog3.FileName;` and check the value of `openFileDialog3.FileName`.

Comment: @BenjaminJ. im writing the code in another project im sure there is no problem with the code if i just remove PicDir=openFileDialog3.FileName and place instead PicDir = C:\pic.jpg the code runs and does the job

Comment: Have you tried debugging as mentioned in my code above? What value ist shown for `openFileDialog3.FileName` in the debugger? Does it show the value `null`?

Comment: @BenjaminJ.so i rewrited the project with the same code and it worked :|