# ShowDialog return type: Form vs. Window

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

In WPF / .Net, both `System.Windows.Window` and `System.Windows.Forms.Form` have the `.ShowDialog` method.

The difference is that the `Windows.Window` version returns a nullable bool (`bool?` or `Nullable<bool>`), while the `Forms.Form` version returns a straight `bool`.

I haven't yet seen the nullable bool ever be null, and cannot find a case where it would be in the MSDN documentation.

Can anyone explain why `Windows.Window.ShowDialog` returns a nullable?  Should I check for it? What does it mean if I see null?

Comment: I think this happens so you can override the ShowDialog() function with your own logic, and return a boolean wether or not something happened. Cant be sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see here: [Window.DialogResult Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx)

> DialogResult is null when the dialog box is shown but neither accepted nor canceled.

Comment: I arrived on that page from here "Window.ShowDialog Method": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Kent Boogaart demonstrates in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987224/why-is-dialogresult-a-nullable-bool-in-wpf/987288#987288) to a very similar question

> When you close the windows, you'll
>   notice that the dialog has a
>   DialogResult of false, whilst the
>   non-dialog has a null DialogResult

So `Windows.Window.ShowDialog` returns a nullable because it uses the DialogResult property which is null when its not a dialog

Answer (score 0):

> why Windows.Window.ShowDialog returns
>   a nullable?

I think that was just an arbitrary implementation choice.  If I were to guess, I would say that returning a nullable bool is a little more lightweight than creating another enum to return the result.  There are three states for a nullable boolean, an that covers all of the bases.

Answer (score 0):

ShowDialog returns the DialogResult of the window, which is a Nullable. While the window is open, DialogResult is null. Once DialogResult is set to true or false, ShowDialog will return that result. Since any close operation on the window will implicitly set DialogResult to false unless it is explicitly set, yes, you can safely ignore null values returned by ShowDialog (DialogResult, on the other hand, can be null if you check it directly). This is simply a result of matching the types exactly, as far as I know.